# Running SQL Script in Excel Macro

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have a question regarding Macros in Excel and how to use them. I recently created a SQL Query that will hit several TFS databases to extract data. I would simply like to run this script from excel such that the output of the script is automatically published in excel with the individual column headers. I have seen this done before in excel by using VB Macros.

As a workaround, I created a small bat file to run sqlcmd, check a sql file containing the script, and finally push the output to a csv file. The only problem with this, is that the CSV's output pushes the results into a single line and does not separate them with headers.

Current code for batfile:

`sqlcmd -E -S TFSServer\TFS2010 -i C:\test\testquery.sql -o C:\test\test.csv`

Comment: Are you saying all the SQL rows are compressed into a single line?  Or that each row is in a single column?

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables, Sorry about that, I meant to say that each row is a single column.

Comment: You should be able to just do `Data > Text to Columns` after the fact.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use an ssis package or ssrs report for dataextraction?  Macros are so... last century.

If you insist on using a macro, here is an example:

```
Dim con As ADODB.Connection, _
cmd As ADODB.Command, _
rs As ADODB.Recordset, _
strSQL As String, _
i As Integer

strSQL = "EXEC SP_StoredProcedureToGetData"

Set con = New ADODB.Connection
con.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=SQLSERVER;" & _
    "Initial Catalog=DATABASE;User ID=USERNAME;Password=PASSWORD"

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = con
    .CommandText = strSQL
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
End With

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
With rs
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .CursorType = adOpenKeyset
    .LockType = adLockBatchOptimistic
End With
Set rs = cmd.Execute

Cells(1, 1) = "Column1"
Cells(1, 2) = "Column2"
Cells(1, 3) = "Column3"
Cells(1, 4) = "Column4"
Cells(1, 5) = "Column5"
Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs

Set con = Nothing
Set cmd = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing
```

Comment: I have a question about your proposed answer. It seems that this code requires you to have the script loaded onto the sql server so it can simply be run, is that correct? If so, that is not possible because we do not want to load any additional stored procedures as this is a internal production server. I was looking to be able to run the script from a client machine/account with read only access.